# Store value changes but doesn't affect computed property in component

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

I'm building a tree view using VueJS and I want to save the last clicked item in a store then use this store to show the last clicked item in a component.

I use a computed property in the the component where I want to show the item. The problem is that when the store changes it doesn't affect the computed property in the component.

The relative code is shown in this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/527884/

```
Vue.component('category-list', {
    template: `
    <div>
  <b>{{selectedCat}}</b>
  <ul>
        <category v-for='(catg, catgIdx) in categories' :category='catg' :key='catgIdx'
                            v-on:category-selected='categorySelected'/>
    </ul>
  </div>
  `,
    props: {
        categories: { type: Array, default: () => [] }
    },
  computed:{
  selectedCat(){
    return bookmarksStore.state.selectedCategory
  }
}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have dependency on reactive data (`data`,`props`) on your `computed`. So, when `bookmarksStore` change, your computed property is not triggered.

I would suggest to use Vuex in your case to create your store.

### Using Vuex

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
      selectedCategory: {name: ""}
  },
  getters: {
    getselectedCategory: state => {
        return state.selectedCategory;
    }
  },
  mutations:{
    selectCategory(state, payload) {
        state.selectedCategory.name = payload
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data: {
...
```

Then, you could use `this.$store.commit('selectCategory', category)` to update the `selectedCategory` of your store and your computed property would look like

```
computed:{
  selectedCat(){
    return this.$store.getters.getselectedCategory
  }
}
```

### Without Vuex

If you don't want to use Vuex, pass your `bookmarksStore` in your Vue root instance data.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    bookmarksStore: new BookmarksStore(),
    ...
```

You can now pass the `bookmarksStore` to the child components using `props` and update it using events passed to the Vue root instance. This way, the `bookmarksStore` being a `props` in each child component, the `computed` property will be triggered.

Comment: can I solve this problem without using vuex? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: I just updated my answer to solve your problem without Vuex. Although I highly recommend using Vuex in your case.

Comment: best answer. Thank you!

Comment: While returning the computed property, can we directly return the state instead of getters? 
`return this.$store.state. selectedCategory ` instead of `return this.$store.getters.getselectedCategory`, will it be reactive still?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components), it is completely feasible